# Using AD LDS for storing Application settings

Tags: adlds

I have just started on LDAP and AD LDS. I know AD LDS can be used to store Application settings. But How?

Imagine I have a Factory, and under Factory I have multiple applications and all these applications need a centralized configuration management. The settings for each application would be more or less the same with little difference.

1. Would AD LDS be a good candidate for this?
2. Is there a good example on How to use AD LDS to store Application settings?